# How to run a command at startup using Startup Application Preferences [Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS x86_64]

Tags: bash, command-line, startup, pop-os, xmodmap

I have a script and want to run it at startup for all users.

My script located in: `~/shell_script/swapkey.sh`

```bash
#!/bin/bash
xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
```

I followed the instruction in [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login) and then added the command to Startup Application Preferences but it didn't work when I reboot my laptop

Here is the file from: `~/.config/autostart/xmodmap.desktop`

```bash
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=/home/sofia/shell_script/swapkey.sh
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name=Swap key
Comment=Run at startup
```

How can I run my script at startup using Startup Application Preferences? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does your swapkey.sh behave normally if you execute it as a standalone application? (run `bash swapkey.sh`). Is the path to that `.sh` correct?